# MySQL Join 3 cascading tables

Tags: php, mysql, select, join, inner-join

I have seen plenty of examples to join multiple tables back to one master table but this query is different in that it cascades.

I have 3 tables similar to the below (simplified for ease):

```
**CONTACTS**     
--------------------------------------------
Cid    name
--------------------------------------------
1      John
2      Peter
3      Karl


**OPPORTUNITIES**
--------------------------------------------
Oid   Cidlink   title
--------------------------------------------
1     2         php lookup script
2     2         php facial recognition
3     3         html email template
4     1         javascript verification

**ATTACHMENTS**
--------------------------------------------
Aid    Oidlink  attachment
--------------------------------------------
1     3         received enquiry
2     3         header and footer done
3     3         pixel trace image done on server
4     2         database structure done      
5     2         html get form done
```

As you can see, attachments link back to opportunities and opportunities relate to contacts.  Attachments do not link directly to contacts except via the opportunity table.

I need to create a recordset including fields from all 3 tables and am struggling.

```
SELECT CONTACTS.*, OPPORTUNITIES.*, ATTACHMENTS.*
FROM ATTACHMENTS
    INNER JOIN OPPORTUNITIES
        ON CONTACTS.Cid = OPPORTUNITIES.Cidlink
    INNER JOIN ATTACHMENTS
        ON OPPORTUNITIES.Oid = ATTACHMENTS.Oidlink

ORDER BY ****whatever****
```

Am I close or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: Why do you have attachments listed twice? shouldn't the first one be `contacts`?  (and yes this is close assuming a record has to be in all 3 tables for you to need it.) otherwise you need to use OUTER joins.

Comment: John would be excluded if you don't use a LEFT join as he has no opportunities with attachments.  By using a LEFT Join you could include John's opportunity with no attachments.  (Note posting the expected results in such questions helps us better understand what you're after.  Consider including expected results on future posts!)  It helps tell the story of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean to have contacts be the first table not attachments...

```
SELECT CONTACTS.*, OPPORTUNITIES.*, ATTACHMENTS.*
FROM ATTACHMENTS  --- This is wrong
INNER JOIN OPPORTUNITIES
  ON CONTACTS.Cid = OPPORTUNITIES.Cidlink
INNER JOIN ATTACHMENTS
  ON OPPORTUNITIES.Oid = ATTACHMENTS.Oidlink
ORDER BY ****whatever****
```

I think you mean (and use aliases easier to read in the long run)

```
SELECT C.*, O.*, A.*
FROM Contacts C
INNER JOIN OPPORTUNITIES O
   ON C.Cid = O.Cidlink
INNER JOIN ATTACHMENTS A
   ON O.Oid = A.Oidlink
ORDER BY ****whatever****
```

Since you indicated you need fields from all 3 tables I'm assuming INNER JOIN is appropriate here; but maybe you want to use an OUTER JOIN to include all contacts?
Include all contacts and their opportunities if they exist.
and include all attachments for opportunities if if they exist)

```
SELECT C.*, O.*, A.*
FROM Contacts C
LEFT JOIN OPPORTUNITIES O
   ON C.Cid = O.Cidlink
LEFT JOIN ATTACHMENTS A
   ON O.Oid = A.Oidlink
ORDER BY ****whatever****
```

For an improved understanding of joins this [Venn Diagram](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) approach from CodingHorror is a good start.

Comment: Thanks xQbert - I'll give it a try.

Comment: Perfect - stupid mistake - this works a treat.  Thank you.

Comment: Not all contacts are needed, neither are all opportunities.  I am using this as part of a search function on fields within A.* but need to capture data from the two parent tables to display relevant information.